# Hibernate - List referencing superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a question regarding hibernate in regards to inheritance.  If I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Person

@Entity
@Table(name="teachers")
@DiscriminatorValue("t")
public class Teacher extends Person 

@Entity
@Table(name="students")
@DiscriminatorValue("s")
public class Student extends Person
```

Then what I want to do is handle all them all generically in the following class:

```
public class Course {

...
@ManyToMany
private List<Person> students;
...

}
```

I would like to be able to treat the students list generically as a List instead of List this way a student or a teacher can be a student.  Is there anyway for me to do this and still have them persist as the Student/Teacher objects?  Is hibernate 'smart' enough to figure out the real class?  Does hibernate have this capability?

Comment: try this List<? extends Person> students

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it then throws:  org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity() defined: ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is just fine, Hibernate can handle this. Whenever an instance of `Student` is  persisted, Hibernate will generate two insert statements, one for the `people` table and another for the `students` table. You can do this for example:

```
Person p = new Student();
session.persist(p);
```

Nothing changes when there is an association. For example:

```
Course c = new Course();
c.students = new ArrayList<Person>();

Person p = new Student();
s.persist(p);

c.people.add(p);
session.persist(c);
```

**PS**: You might want to change `Course.students` to `Course.people` because that list can hold `Teacher` instances also.